Running Flask in Debug Mode
I am working on my first Flask app. All I am trying to do is to make sure that my Flask server restarts after I edit the hello.py file.
Here is my app structure:

Here is hello.py:
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") 
def hello(): 
    return "Hello World"    

and here is my .flask_env file:
FLASK_APP=hello.py
FLASK_DEBUG=True   

When I run the app in debug more using
flask run --debug

I get the following error:
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.

What am I missing?

The file name is .flaskenv and not .flask_env. That is explained in the documentation. You can also see that in the source code. That's why your flask env variables are not being read.
...
        if path or os.path.isfile(".env") or os.path.isfile(".flaskenv"):
...

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/255c8d66af6daff3eaa063ea0819e185d4d1e214/src/flask/cli.py#L716

You can run Flask in debug mode by adding this to the end of your hello.py file. This should run Flask in debug mode.
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


What terminal command I need to run in order to run it in debug mode? If I use the same command as before, it gives me the same error.

You can use python hello.py or rename your file to app.py and run flask run

There are probably many different methods, but here are three. I usually default to #1.

Start the app inside of the file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Now you can run it like python hello.py.

Rename the file from hello.py to app.py.

When you run flask run without the --app flag, it searches for one in the current directory. I think that the only filenames it recognizes are app and wsgi. So, you can rename it to either of those and flask will automatically run it.

Use the --app flag.
Just add the app flag...run it like flask --app=hello:app run.

As a side note, you do not need both the FLASK_DEBUG and --debug flag. You can choose between them.
Another side note: I am certainly not sure about this, but you might need to ues load_dotenv to get flask to take config from the flask_dotenv file.
